# Golang + AJAX(JQ) + JSONP

Tags: ajax, golang, cors, jsonp

Привет. Есть задача. Не могу решить.

1. Локально поднимается golang сервер http://localhost:64000/
2. По адресу /login пользователь в форму вводит логин и пароль
3. Эти данные надо отправить на сервер (там тоже GO), например, по адресу site.ru/login_check с использованием ajax
4. Сервер получает данные показывает мне в консоли и шлет ответ на локальную машину, например, true.

Все. Т.е. я должен отправить на сервер запрос и получить от него ответ без перезагрузки страницы.

---

Что я делаю?

1) JS + JQ получаю данные и отправляю

```
function test(){
   let site = "http://site.ru/login_check";
   // Формирую строку для преобразования в JSON
   user_data = '{ "login" : "'+ $('#login').val() +'", "password" : "'+ $("#password").val() +'"}';
   // Преобразую в JSON
   user_data = JSON.parse(user_data);

   // Выполняю ajax запрос
   $.ajax({
      url: auth_url,
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      crossDomain: true,
      success: function(data){
         alert(data);
      },
      error: function(){
         alert("Ошибка");
      }
   });
}
```

2) Пишу код на GO на сервере. Данные пока не получаю, но пытаюсь отправить какой-нибудь ответ.

```
func login_check_Handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
   fmt.Print("Вход!") // Дает мне возможность увидеть, что Ajax соединился с сервером (прошел по адресу)
   // Дальше просто использую пример
   mapD := map[string]int{"apple": 5, "lettuce": 7}
   mapB, _ := json.Marshal(mapD)
   fmt.Fprintf(w, string(mapB))
}

PS. 
import (
   "fmt"
   "encoding/json"
   "net/http"
)
```

3) В итоге в браузере вылезает ошибка

```
ncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

А во вкладке Application это. Получается что вроде как я что-то получаю но что не так я не понимаю. И всегда вылезает alert("Ошибка"). 
[image]

PS. Другими способами кроссдоменный запросы не получилось сделать. Может посоветуете что можно сделать и как получить данные отправленные с localhost на site.ru в golang.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо кроссдоменного AJAX можно данные отправить с сервера, где пользователь логинится, делаем AJAX запрос на свой же сервер, где форма login, а оттуда уже перекидываем запрос куда надо, и можем на сервере обработать ответ удалённого сервера.

Comment: Действительно. Именно так и сделал. Получилось гораздо проще.